# Why does the Nexus 7 have a notification bar?

Tags: notifications, nexus-7

In some of the reviews I have read of the new Nexus 7 tablet, it seems to have a notification bar. For example:

[image: Nexus 7 notification bar]

Why is that? I was under the impression that Android 3.0+ on tablets ditches the bar for a tray in the lower-right corner, next to the software buttons:

[image: Galaxy Tab 7.0 plus]

So why is this? Did they ditch the tray in 4.1? Is it because the units currently reviewed are not final, and the ones that will be sold will have the tray? Is it because it's too small at 7"? (although, the galaxy tab shown above is 7" as well, but maybe they changed the size limit in 4.1?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apparently, in the SDK the 7" form factor has the phone layout and tablet apps. The 10" form factor will still be tablet layout and tablet apps. I also heard that in 4.1 they expanded the functionality of the notification area so that notifications can do more (e.g. Reply to sms from notification area). I don't know how true that is though.

Comment: The expanded functionality of the notification bar was announced in Google I/O a several days ago. You might want to watch the opening keynote for some demos of Jelly Bean.

Comment: I didn't actually watch the IO (meant to but still haven't gotten around to it), I was reading up on it though and seen that. Must see what it's like because it sounds pretty good.

Comment: @ConnDarcy See the notifications UI on the JellyBean platform highlights here http://developer.android.com/about/versions/jelly-bean.html#ui (though that's on a phone form factor), note the call-back and message-back buttons below the  missed call, the preview text from the 3 unread text messages, and the transport controls on the playing music.